# Pthreads-How do I solve this concurrency problem

Tags: c

The program consists of a separate file called circular buffer, the header for that file, and the thread test. What the program is supposed to do is that I create a buffer with the size i want, and then i tell him to add/delete numbers from that buffer. For example, ./program 3 2 1 will create a buffer with size 3, and will add 2 elements to the buffer and delete 1. The problem is that i don't have control over the concurrency, as when I run the program it will add 1 -> delete 1 -> add 1. I want it to add/delete the number of times i ask before switching to the next part.

I've tried different options like adding mutex or variables, but im doing something wrong. I'll add the part of the code that needs to be changed below:

```c
//THIS IS THE HEADER OF BUFFER_CIRCULAR.h
#ifndef _BUFFER
#define _BUFFER
// Definición de la estructura búfer 
// El búfer no tiene tamaño fijo
struct Buffer_Circular {
    long *Buff; // Puntero al bloque de memoria dónde se almacenan los item
    int Nelementos; // Número máximo de elementos que se pueden almacenar
    int Extrae; // Indica la posición del próximo item a extraer
    int Inserta;    // Indica dónde se insertará el próximo item a almacenar
    int Pendientes_Consumir;    // Indica el número de items que aún no han sido extraídos
};

// Función de creación del búfer circular
// Parámetro de entrada:
//  Capacidad: número máximo de elementos que pueden ser almacenados
// Devuelve
//  Si no hay error retorna valor cero, en caso contrario devuelve un valor negativo
int Crea_Buffer(int Capacidad);

// Función que inserta un item en el búfer
// Parámetros de entrada:
//  Nuevo item a almacenar en el búfer
void *Inserta_Item(void *item);

// Función que extrae un item del búfer
// Parámetros de entrada:
//  Puntero que almacenará el item a extraer
void *Extrae_Item(void *item);

// Función que retorna el número de ítems pendientes de consumir
int Num_Pendientes_Consumir();

// Función que retorna la capacidad máxima del búfer
int Capacidad_Buffer();
#endif
```

```c
// THIS IS CIRCULAR_BUFER DOC

#include <stdlib.h> // Requerido para malloc
#include <unistd.h>  // Requerido para Sleep  
#include <stdio.h>   // Requerido para lecturas y escrituras en los canales de entrada/salida


// Se incluye fichero cabecera en el que se declara los tipos y funciones de manejo del buffer circular
#include "Buffer_Circular.h"

// Puntero a una estructura de tipo Buffer_Circular
struct Buffer_Circular *Buffer=NULL;

// Función de creación del búfer circular
int Crea_Buffer(int Capacidad)
{
    long *p0;   
    struct Buffer_Circular *p1;
    int i;

    if (Capacidad <= 0) return -1;
    p0 = malloc( sizeof(long) * Capacidad);
    p1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Buffer_Circular));
    if ( (p0 != NULL) && (p1 != NULL) ) {
        Buffer = p1;
        Buffer->Buff = p0;
        Buffer->Inserta = 0;
        Buffer->Extrae = 0;
        Buffer->Nelementos = Capacidad;
        Buffer->Pendientes_Consumir = 0;
        for(i=0;i<Capacidad;i++) Buffer->Buff[i]=-1;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}


// Función que retorna el número de ítems pendientes de consumir
int Num_Pendientes_Consumir(){
return Buffer->Pendientes_Consumir;
}

// Función que retorna la capacidad máxima del búfer
int Capacidad_Buffer(){
return Buffer->Nelementos;
}

// Inserta un item en el búfer y actualiza los campos de datos del búfer
void *Inserta_Item(void *item)
{
    Buffer->Buff[Buffer->Inserta] = (long)item;
    if ( (long)item % 2 )
        sleep(1);
    printf("Se ha insertado en %d el item %ld\n",Buffer->Inserta,(long)item);
    Buffer->Inserta = (Buffer->Inserta+1) % Buffer->Nelementos;
    Buffer->Pendientes_Consumir++;
}

// Extrae un elemento del búfer y actualiza los campos de datos del búfer
void *Extrae_Item(void *item)
{
    item = (void *)(Buffer->Buff[Buffer->Extrae]);
    Buffer->Buff[Buffer->Extrae] = -1;
    printf("Se extrajo de %d el item %ld\n",Buffer->Extrae,(long)item);
    Buffer->Extrae = (Buffer->Extrae+1) % Buffer->Nelementos;
    Buffer->Pendientes_Consumir--;
}
```

```c
// Prueba concurrente de acceso al búfer
// Se lanzan hilos productores y consumidores
// Al no haber sincronización entre los hilos,
// el resultado es que se puede corromper el búfer

//Archivos cabecera del sistema
#include <stdlib.h> // Requerido para atoi
#include <stdio.h> // Requerido para printf
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "Buffer_Circular.h"

// Función que comprueba y captura los parámetros pasados por línea de órdenes
void Comprobar_Argumentos(int argc, char *argv[], int *dim, int *np, int *nc);

// Hilo Productor: inserta un item en el búfer
void *Productor(void *item);

// Hilo Consumidor: extrae un item del búfer
void *Consumidor(void *item);

// Rutina que lanza los hilos productores y consumidores
void test_recurso_hilos(int np, int nc);


// Función que comprueba y captura los parámetros pasados por línea de órdenes
void Comprobar_Argumentos(int argc, char *argv[], int *dim, int *np, int *nc){
    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Invocación incorrecta: ./fich_ejec dim_buff num_prod num_cons\n");      
        exit(-1);
    }

    *dim = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (*dim<1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Invocación incorrecta. La dimensión del búfer debe ser >0: ./fich_ejec dim_buff num_prod num_cons\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    *np = atoi( argv[2] );
    if ( *np < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Invocación incorrecta. El número de hilos productores debe ser >0: ./fich_ejec dim_buff num_prod num_cons\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    *nc = atoi( argv[3] );
    if ( *nc < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Invocación incorrecta. El número de hilos consumidores debe ser >0: ./fich_ejec dim_buff num_prod num_cons\n");
        exit(-1);
    }   
}

// this is the part from the tests that needs to be changed
//Num_Pendientes_Consumir() returns the number of how many are left to consume
//Capacidad_Buffer() returns the size of the buffer

// Producer thread: adds item to buffer. 
void *Productor(void *item){
    while (Num_Pendientes_Consumir() == Capacidad_Buffer()) ;

    Inserta_Item(item);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// Extracting thread: extracts item from buffer
void *Consumidor(void *item)
{
    while (Num_Pendientes_Consumir() == 0) ;
    Extrae_Item(item);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// Rutina que lanza los hilos productores y consumidores
void test_recurso_hilos(int np, int nc)
{
  pthread_t *productores;
  pthread_t *consumidores;
  int ret;
  long int i;
  void* dummy;

  productores=malloc(np*sizeof(pthread_t));
  if (productores==NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error en la petición de memoria para pthread_t productores\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  consumidores=malloc(nc*sizeof(pthread_t));
  if (consumidores==NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error en la petición de memoria para pthread_t consumidores\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  for(i=0; i<np; i++) {
    ret = pthread_create(&productores[i], NULL, Productor, (void *)i);
    if (ret) {
    errno=ret;
    fprintf(stderr,"error %d: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }
  }

  for (i=0; i<nc; i++) {
    ret=pthread_create(&consumidores[i], NULL, Consumidor, (void *)i);
    if (ret) {
    errno=ret;
    fprintf(stderr,"error %d: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }
  }

  for(i=0;i<np;i++) {
    ret=pthread_join(productores[i],&dummy);
    if (ret) {
    errno=ret;
    fprintf(stderr,"Error %d en el join del hilo productor %d: %s\n",errno,i,strerror(errno));
    exit(-1);
    }
  }

  for(i=0;i<nc;i++) {
    ret=pthread_join(consumidores[i],&dummy);
    if (ret) {
    errno=ret;
    fprintf(stderr,"Erro %d en el join del hilo consumidor %d: %s\n",errno,i,strerror(errno));
    exit(-1);
    }
  }
}

// Función main:
// Invocación:
//  # ./fich_ejec dim_buff num_prod num_cons
//  fich_ejec: nombre del archivo que contiene el código ejecutable
//  dim_buff: dimensión del búfer (>0)
//  num_prod: número de hilos productores (>=0)
//  num_cons: número de hilos consumidores (>=0)
//
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int dim,np,nc;

  printf("»»» Comienza la prueba del búfer...\n");
  Comprobar_Argumentos(argc, argv,&dim,&np,&nc);
  if (Crea_Buffer(dim) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error al crear buffer\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  test_recurso_hilos(np,nc);
  printf("»»» Fin de la prueba del búfer\n");
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Without a [mcve], it's impossible to help you. Behavior of your program depends on `Num_Pendientes_Consumir`, `Inserta_Item` and `Extrae_Item`. Generally, if you have a single consumer-single producer fifo, you don't need synchronization if you write it properly. `pthread_exit` is also unnecessary.

Comment: If you want to serialize the operations as you describe, then what's the purpose of using threads?

Comment: Actually, the proper way to exit a thread is via `pthread_exit()`  For one reason:  the function that calls `pthread_join()` expects a returned value that is well defined, even if it is NULL

Comment: Just changed it and added the whole of the Buffer_Circular file. And the purpose is just that i wanted to try them and learn how to use them and i just used this example

Comment: the (newly) posted code includes a home grown header file: `Buffer_Circular.h`  With out the contents of that file, we cannot reproduce the problem

Comment: the posted code is missing the `main()` function

Comment: the main function is included in the tests, i just got that part of the file because the rest is huge, but ill edit it now

Comment: @user3629249: `pthread_exit` is called implicitly for all (almost) all threads after they return from their function, so if you don't care about the return value it's unnecessary. I agree that it's not a problem though, and perhaps it can help emphasize that the function is meant to run on a different thread.

Comment: Now everything is posted. I didn't post it the first time because its just a problem located in just one place so i didnt want to fill the post with all the code

Comment: regarding: `long *p0;   
    struct Buffer_Circular *p1;` in function: `Crea_Buffer()`  these are local variables,  They go 'out-of-scope' when the function exits.  The pointers to that dynamic memory is invisible to the rest of the code.  1) this will result in memory leaks 2) they will not be usable in the rest of the program

Comment: @user3629249: `Buffer = p1` assigns the address to a global variable though. It's lousy practice from a design perspective, but not a bug in itself. I'd say this question would be a better fit for Code Review.

Comment: regarding: `#define _BUFFER`  In C, an underscore followed by a capital letter is 'reserved' for the system  Suggest: `BUFFER_H`

Comment: @ULPGCstudent: I would do two things: 1) remove the `Buffer` global variable and change all your functions to accept the pointer to `struct Buffer_Circular`. Why have a header file which can only work with a single global buffer? 2) Remove the `.Pendientes_Consumir` and calculate this value using head and tail pointers on each call. This way your producer thread only writes to the head, and the consumer thread only writes to the tail, and there should be no race conditions. What you are doing now (writing to two fields, and writing to a field from two threads) will cause bugs.

Comment: regarding: `ret = pthread_create(&productores[i], NULL, Productor, (void *)i);
    if (ret) {
    errno=ret;
    fprintf(stderr,"error %d: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }`  The returned value from `pthread_create()` is 0 or -1.  Do not use that to overlay the value in `errno`.  Suggest: `if( pthread_create(&productores[i], NULL, Productor, (void *)i); ) {
perror( "pthread_create failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing.   When the posted code is compiled. it results in 15 warnings, several of what are serious

Comment: regarding: `void *Extrae_Item(void *item)`  This signature states that the function returns a `void *`  however, there is no `return` statement in the function.  This results in the compiler outputting a message:  *untitled.c: In function ‘Extrae_Item’:  ...warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]*  this is just one of the many warnings that needs to be fixed.  Suggest changing the signature to: `void Extrae_Item(void *item)`

Comment: regarding: `void *Extrae_Item(void *item)
{
    item = (void *)(Buffer->Buff[Buffer->Extrae]);`  This is overlaying the parameter with the value extracted from 'Buffer'.  Note this does NOT update the value of 'item' in the function that calls this function

Comment: regarding function: `Extrae_item()`  Suggest correcting to be: `void Extrae_Item( void )
{
    printf("Se extrajo de %d el item %d\n",Buffer->Extrae, Buffer->Buff[Buffer->Extrae]);
    Buffer->Buff[Buffer->Extrae_Item(Extrae] = -1;
    Buffer->Extrae = (Buffer->Extrae+1) % Buffer->Nelementos;
    Buffer->Pendientes_Consumir--;
}`